# Eclipse crashes during SVN merges

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

I am currently using **Eclipse Version: 3.5.1**. It works perfectly in normal conditions, even with the SVN plugin, the faulty component that I am about to talk about now.

The thing is that whenever I am conducting a merge, eclipse shuts down. It just crashes without even leaving an error message or anything else. It happens too often so that I can hardly normally. I am now using **RapidSVN** for merges. However, I would still like to know if there is any way to improve my eclipse condition.

Comment: well, you know.. I am not sure what the cause really is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a different SVN plugin for Eclipse:  Subclipse http://subclipse.tigris.org/

I've never had any problems with Subclipse merging.

Comment: I was using 1.4, and I am switching to 1.6 to see if there is any improvement.

Comment: Interesting...  Yeah, I must admit, I never tried it with 1.4.  Only with Java 5 and beyond.  I'm curious if it works out for you :)